# Log4j2 ouptput to File is succesful but not to Console using Ant

Tags: ant, log4j2

When running Ant, Log4j2 ouput goes to File Mylog.log correctly but nothing gets displayed on the console. What am I missing from build.xml or the log4j2.xml?
Version: log4j2 2.0, Ant 4.11
But when using Eclipse's run as Junit, displays the Log4j2 output to both console and file log successfully.

```
In the Log4j2.xml, both Appenders to Console and File have been created.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="All">
      <Appenders>
          <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT" >
              <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
          </Console>
          <File name="FileLogger" fileName="MyLog.log" append="false">
              <PatternLayout pattern="%d %t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/>
          </File> 
      </Appenders>
      <Loggers>
          <Logger name="com.site" level="All" />
          <Root >
              <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="All"/>
              <AppenderRef ref="FileLogger" level="All"/> 
          </Root>
      </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

In the build.xml, I have included the path to log4j2.xml in the classpath for "junit" target

```
<target name="junit">
    <classpath>
        <path refid="log4j2_config"/>
```

---

In the test class, the getLogger is included.
private static final Logger log4j = LogManager.getLogger("com.site");

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration, the Logger with  name="com.site" does not have an appender-ref. So that logger does not do anything and can be removed. Your root logger will handle all events so that is fine.

I suspect that the difference between running your JUnit tests with Ant and in Eclipse is a classpath issue. Try specifying the full absolute path in `<path refid="/full/path/to/log4j2_config"/>` to see if that makes any difference.

You can also use a system property to specify the location of the config file:
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#config_location